# For loop with step execution time restriction

Tags: r

I want to make a restriction on execution time for every step of the for loop. Simply, if the step didn't complete in 10 seconds, then go `next`.

To be more specific, here is some code.

```
myComplicatedFunction <- function(obj, ...) { <some code here> }
x # something to process
x_result <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(x))
for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    x_result[[i]] <- 
        processNotMoreThanXSeconds(
            givenTime = 10,
            myComplicatedFunction(x[i]),
            didNotComplete = function() "Time's up!"
        )
}
```

My question is, how to declare such function `processNotMoreThanXSeconds`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `setTimeLimit` (it is part of base R):

```
setTimeLimit({

  Sys.sleep(7)

}, elapsed = 5)
```

If the time limit is reached the function will return an error (like if you run the above, processing takes 7 secs but the limit is 5). You can tie this up with `try` in order to handle the error and continue the loop:

```
myerror <- try({

   setTimeLimit({

     Sys.sleep(7)

   }, elapsed = 5)
}, silent = TRUE)

class(myerror)
#[1] "try-error"
```

Then use an if-else statement to check if there was an error and continue. Something like:

```
if (class(myerror) == 'try-error') {
  next
}
```